# rspec active record testing error on serialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rspec, shoulda

i'am using rspec to testing my model that should serialize a json.
btw this is show an error in my console

this is my rspec
require 'rails_helper'

```
RSpec.describe Image, type: :model do
  it { should belong_to :user }
  it { should serialize(:path) }
end
```

this is my image model

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessor :imagepath_data
  serialize :path, JSON
  mount_uploader :path, ImageUploader
end
```

when i run bundle exec rspec its throw an error

```
Image should serialize :path
 Failure/Error: it { should serialize(:path) }

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `cast_type' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn:0x000000064a81d8>
```

can anyone solve this

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue in GitHub with a [PR](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/pull/965) that was merged 15 days ago into their rails 5 branch...looks like the last update of the gem was ~30 days ago, so might have to apply that patch by hand

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to update `shoulda-mathcers`

https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/pull/965/commits/91c1d6a63ee80a1c024da45cf40451dac3aa9bed